# Android: is it ok to hold references to system services?

Tags: android, singleton

When my singleton is initialized, it is passed a `Context` (as advised in Android docs). I use that Context to get the `ConnectivityManager`.

Later I want to access `ConnectivityManager` again, **but this time I don't have a `Context`** (because saving a `Context` is bad etc).

Is it ok if during the singleton initialization I keep the `ConnectivityManager` (or any other system service, for that matter)?

I doubt that the reasons to avoid saving app contexts statically apply to system services as well, but I could be wrong.

**EDIT** the answer to the "duplicate" question ignored the core of my question, which is I don't have a reference to the app context when I need that service.

And the question itself only asks about leaks.